# How to prevent MUI X Datagrid styles from applying to another MUI X Datagrid which is its child in the detail pane?

Tags: css, material-ui, styled-components, mui-x-data-grid

I want to customize the styling of my data grid by using `styled`. I also want to put another datagrid inside the detail panes of the parent data grid.

However, the detail pane's data grid must be styled ***differently***.

The problem is that the parent's styling ***also*** applies to the child.

A rought example:

```
const Parent = styled(DataGridPremium)(({ theme }) => {
  return {
    "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders": {
      borderRadius: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  };
});

const Child = styled(DataGridPremium)(({ theme }) => {
  return {
    "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders": {
      borderTopRightRadius: theme.spacing(2),
      borderTopLeftRadius: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  };
});

const ChildHasParentsStylesToo = () => (
  <Parent getDetailPanelContent={() => <Child />}></Parent>
);
```

What is an ideal way to make sure the `Parent` styles do not apply to `Child`?